# how to remove a foreign key constraint using flask and alembic

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using **flask** with **alembic** and i have the two tables below linked by a **Foreign key constraint**:

```
table_one = Table("table_one", meta.Base.metadata,
    Column("id", BigInteger, primary_key=True),
    Column("filename", VARCHAR(65535)),
    Column("mission", VARCHAR(65535)),
)


table_two = Table("table_two", meta.Base.metadata,
    Column("id", BigInteger, primary_key=True),
    Column("file_id", BigInteger, ForeignKey("table_one.id")),
    Column("username", ArrowType(timezone=True)),
```

I am trying to get rid of `table_one` with the alembic revision below

```
def upgrade():
    op.drop_table('table_one')
    op.drop_constraint('table_two_id_fkey', 'table_two', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_column('table_two', 'file_id')
    op.drop_column('table_two', 'id')


def downgrade():
    op.add_column('table_two', sa.Column('id', sa.BIGINT(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False))
    op.add_column('table_two', sa.Column('file_id', sa.BIGINT(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True))
    op.create_foreign_key('table_two_file_id_fkey', 'table_two', 'table_one', ['file_id'], ['id'])
    op.create_table('table_one',
    sa.Column('id', sa.BIGINT(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('filename', sa.VARCHAR(length=65535), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('mission', sa.VARCHAR(length=65535), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='table_one_pkey')
    )
```

but unfortunately there seem to be an issue with the cascade and i am facing the error below:

```
psycopg2.errors.DependentObjectsStillExist: cannot drop table table_one because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint table_two_file_id_fkey on table table_tow depends on table table_one
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

Does anyone have an idea how on to solve this issue?

Comment: I recommend you drop the constraint from table2 to table1  prior to dropping table1. You  should check out `drop ... cascade` as well, but make sure you understand what it is potentially going to do prior to running it.

Comment: @JonSG do you mind showing the answer with codes, i am really stuck. thank you for your time.

Comment: Try moving `op.drop_table('table_one')` to the end of `upgrade()` rather than the beginning of it.

Comment: @JonSG it worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone is trying to drop a foreign key as the question title says:
You can remove a foreign key using the drop_constraint() function in alembic

```
op.drop_constraint(constraint_name="FK_<target>_<source>", table_name="<source>")
```